# Running a while loop and retrieving row names from dataset on R

Tags: r, while-loop, statistics

What I'm trying to do right now is to get, from the mtcars dataset on R, the car names that are that have an hp column value of less than 200.  The thing is that I want the car names and I don't want to go back and rematch all the numbers with the corresponding car names.  How might I go about doing that?  Here's what I have so far:

```
> carvector<-mtcars["hp"]
> while (i<=32)
+ i<-i+1
if (mtcars[i,1]<200)
p<-mtcars[i,1]
```

Its not quite working and I guess I'm closer to storing the values than the names of the cars.  How can I make sure the names are not lost?  How do I dispose of the values I don't want?

Comment: You'll want `rownames( mtcars[ mtcars$hp < 200, ] )`. The row names are not located in the first column, but are a separate attribute.

Comment: @Frank - I think `rownames(mtcars)[mtcars$hp < 200]` might be better since you won't be subsetting the entire data

Comment: @RichardScriven I agree

Comment: Okay but what exactly is this function doing in terms of looping?